# Unix find -exec: Why do the following behaviors differ?

Tags: bash

The following works as intended:

```
$ find . -name .git -exec dirname '{}' \;
./google/guava
./JetBrains/intellij-community
./zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
```

But the following only returns dots:

```
$ find . -name .git -exec echo "$(dirname '{}')" \;
.
.
.
```

Why is that, and how can I use `$(dirname '{}')` in a `find -exec` command?

Please note, I am asking about UNIX `find` (OS X and FreeBSD, specifically), not GNU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason for behaviour difference

Your shell is evaluating the `$(dirname)` before find, leading to this command being executed :

```
find . -name .git -exec echo . ;
```

### Other ways to do this

- You can of course use shell expansion inside find, by calling another shell yourself (or better, calling a script using the shell you want as shebang).
  In other words:

  ```
  find . -name .git -exec sh -c 'dirname {}' \;
  ```
- Solution without `dirname` (POSIX, faster, one less subprocess to call) :

  ```
  find . -name .git -exec sh -c 'path={}; echo "${path%/*}" ' \;
  ```
- Combing [/u/tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972527/1011859) (upvote him not me) with the find optimization :

  ```
  find . -name .git -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "${f%/*}"; done' _ {} \+
  ```

Comment: Not sure about this. If in my GNU find I type `find . -name .git -exec echo "$(echo hello '{}')" \;` I get `hello <result>`.

Comment: Oh, right, of course. Any idea how I can process the output of each line of `find` in its `-exec` clause before doing more with it?

Comment: @fedorqui His results correspond to what happen if `dirname` is executed first. Are you running this in a shell ? @Daniel Li what about a dedicated script (with `!/bin/bash` as first line) ?

Comment: @pistache, so something like this? `find . -name .git -exec bash -c 'echo $(dirname {})' \;`

Comment: @pistache Scripting is a possibility, but I'm trying to ideally use a one-liner.

Comment: That would work yes. If you want to stick to a one-liner, anubhava's solution is better and it doesn't require spawning a new process for each file.

Comment: I don't believe Unix find has a `-printf` switch.

Comment: @pistache Thanks for the pointers. If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer to include my `bash -c` solution and mark it as answered.

Comment: `echo $(dirname)` is just a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).

Comment: `echo "${path%/*}"` needs double quotes, like I show here, otherwise you will mangle any match which contains a shell metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `gnu find` then you can ditch `dirname` and use `printf`:

```
find . -name .git -printf "%h\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is to run `-exec sh` (or `-exec bash` if you need Bash features).

```
find . -name .git -exec sh -c 'for f; do dirname "$f"; done' _ {} \+
```

`dirname` can easily be replaced with something simpler, but in the general case, this is a useful pattern for when you want a shell to process the results from `find`.

`-exec ... \+` is running the shell on as many matches as possible, instead of executing a separate shell for each match.  This optimization is not available in all versions of `find`.

If you have completely regular file names (no newlines in the results, etc) you might be better off with something like

```
find . -name .git | sed 's%/[^/]*$%%'
```

However, *assuming* that file names will be regular is a huge recurring source of bugs.  Don't do that for a general-purpose tool.

Comment: Very nice optimization, though I'm not sure it's available in UNIX find.  `find . -name .git -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "${f%/*}"; done' _ {} \+` is a good combination of hacks :)

Comment: @pistache You need double quotes in there, though.

Comment: True, thanks. Corrected the post. Your post should be the accepted answer, this optimization looks available in UNIX find.

Comment: Nice! So this kind of buffers as many results of `find` as possible and loops through them with the `for` loop

Comment: Not sure what exactly you try to mean with "UNIX find" but it's in POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html